# accessing ios photos and uploading to a webserver

Tags: ios

I am trying to build an iOS application that will display all of the iOS device's photos in a view. The user should then be able to click each photo to select (multiple selections allowed) then after selecting, upload the photos to a webserver.

Is it possible to access the photos that are controlled by the Photos application? Does anyone know of any efficient way to get access to the photos (third party framework) and/or a tutorial?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple's developer site lists the [Assets Library Framework](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AssetsLibrary/Reference/AssetsLibraryFramework/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009730) as a way "to access the pictures and videos managed by the Photos application." The documentation there is fairly extensive, and looking around the dev site more should yield several tutorials and example apps.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK you can't grab all images from camera roll and use them in your app but you can have a UIImagePickerController that lets the user choose the image from their camera roll and a delegate is fired when they select one (or take a picture depending on how you set it up) then you can use that image in your app.

Comment: Look at UIPickerViewController for more info:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html